# dart http: how to send a MultipartRequest using a client?

Tags: flutter, dart, http, httprequest, multipart

I'm trying to send a `MultipartRequest`  http request containing an image. According to [the docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartRequest-class.html), I should create a `MultipartRequest` object, then call `.send()` on it. However, [the docs for the `.send()` method](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/BaseRequest/send.html) say that:

> This automatically initializes a new Client and closes that client once the request is complete. If you're planning on making multiple requests to the same server, you should use a single Client for all of those requests.

Usually, I would call `client.post(url)` with a normal request. How do I use my created `Client` object with a `MultipartRequest`?

Comment: So you want to upload an image or file to an API? Did you try dio package?

Comment: @KamrulHasanJony no, i read on Reddit that it has some issues. Besides, this question is about using http, not about how to send an image to an API